# When was Kite shown as a little girl?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

When Gon talked with Gin on episode 146, he told him that Kite turned into a little girl.

I can't recall that scene anywhere in the series, can anyone tell me when/how it happened and where it was shown?

Answer (score 3):

- **When**: The first time the reborned-Kaito (or Kite) is shown in the manga is in Chapter 316 (picture shown below). This event takes place when Gon is still injured from his fight with Neferpitou and right before the King's death and end of the Chimera Ant's arc. Gon later meets Kaito in Chapter 337.
- **How**: Some humans that were killed and digested by the Queen are reincarnated into her offspring (only some because the number of digested humans far exceeds that of the Queen's children, and not all of them have human memories though). However, Neferpitou kept Kaito's body instead of feeding it to the Queen and therefore does not fall into the previously mentioned category. From this wikia article:

> Ging Freecss hypothesizes that Kite's survival has something to do with his ability "Crazy Slot"; whereby there is a number that will only appear when Kite has a strong will to survive and does not wish to die.

When a human was killed an fed to
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Spoilers galore:

> Kite was killed and was fed to the ant queen. When the queen was killed, she had one last baby, a little girl. That little girl was known to be Kite because she rejected the name her caretakers gave her and referred to herself as Kite. This happened in Episode 92.

Please see this [wikia](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Kite_(Chimera_Ant)) entry for more information.

Comment: It wasn't mentioned that kite turned into a girl in episode 92 (more like 136).
But now I know that Gon could be informed right before he met Gin.

Comment: That's correct, that's when he was discovered.

Answer (score -1):

As the asker may have seen in episode 146,

> Ging told Gon that Kite's weapon had a special setting which only activated when Kite was in fear of his life.  The episode did not state this specifically, but implies this is what led to his reincarnation.

Episode 147 begins with a long metaphysical monologue from Koala

> to the reincarnated Kite.  Koala, who also remembers his life as a human assassin, wanted to apologize and explain for shooting the girl who Kite now looks like.  He goes deep into his past history and his speculations on reincarnation itself.  Koala hopes that the girl's actual soul had moved on, past the cycle of reincarnation.    He suspects this is why Kite's soul now occupies what would have been her body.  Koala had likely been planning on suicide after talking to Kite.  Kite stops him and gives another option -- work for Kite and apologize every day.  I gathered that Kite was offering a path for Koala to build up some positive Karma.  He accepts.

Previous answers mentioned earlier episodes which described Kite was a girl.  Those were just quick mentions or a quick scene.  It was not until watching episode 147 that I understood the bigger picture.  The aforementioned [Wikia article](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Kite) explains a lot of this as well, but watch episode 147 as it contains the main explanation.

Comment: Perhaps it might be more useful to furnish the details here. You may want to include spoiler tags if you feel that that might be the reason why your answer is short. A short description or the explanation may be helpful here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; I'll add some more info.  I was wondering why my answer had been down-voted.  With the main question worded as "When was Kite shown ...", I thought an episode number would be adequate.

Comment: Interesting--my answer received a 2nd down-vote after extending it.  Could someone explain what they didn't like?  It is directly responsive to the "can anyone tell me when/how it happened" part of the OP's question.  It also added information not contained in the original answer.  Now that a third person has answered there may be overlap, but I believe the 2nd down vote occurred before then.

Comment: I didnt downvote at all. I think your answer probably okay. I don't watch the series though.